# How do I change the color of all hyperlinks in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net, formatting

How do I change the text color and underline color of all hyperlinks in a draw.io shape's text?

I have a diagram with dark colored shapes and white text, however hyperlinks are formatting as the standard blue, and do not have enough contrast with my shape colors.

Selecting the hyperlink and setting the text color to white works for the text, but leaves a blue underline.

By editing the HTML, I can use an inline style on each  element, but it's extremely tedious, and it would be difficult for others in my organization to update.

Is there a style property I can use in the "Edit Style" function?